# SSIS package creates a file when it cannot find one

Tags: excel, file, ssis, package

SSIS package created in VS 2019.
The package Imports an Excel file & fails if file not found (as expected).
This runs fine from SSIS application window.
However, when triggered from SQL Server Agent (SSMS 18.8) job, an empty excel file is created with a random hex sheet name if it cannot find the file it was looking for; the job fails with an error.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: I can't speak for anyone else, but I'm going to need a lot more information as I've never seen this behaviour with SSIS. Add a ScreenShot of the Control Flow, any Data Flows within the package. Right click on the SQL Server Agent Job and choose Script Job to new window and add all of those items into your question and see if that doesn't help us identify what is going on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question is simple, when there is no file to ingest, the package creates a file! HAS ANYONE EXPERIENCED THIS?